# Angular Meta tags for social media not crawl

Tags: angular, metadata, meta-tags

I am developing angular 9 application. I have added dynamic meta tags. Tags are changing page wise dynamically but when we see page source code on browser it's showing index.html page default meta tags. I am changing title, description, keywords & canonical tags.

[image]

[image]

You can see on both pages we got diffent meta tags as per page but when we look for Page Source (CTRL+ u) on browser it is showing index.html default meta tags.

[image: You can see on both pages we got diffent meta tags as per page but when we look for Page Source (CTRL+ u) on browser it is showing index.html default meta tags.]

Comment: For seo purpose you may be need to use angular univarsal

Answer (score 1):

You are changing meta tags page wise (dynamically) but this changes are only seen inside an actual browser, because this only happens after the pages are rendered inside the browser.

the problem is that the bots that most of social media networks (such as Twitter or Facebook & etc.) use to fetch the meta tags can Not render Java-script properly
so that only thing they can get is the `index.html`

if you'd like to get meta tags dynamically for each page you need to use SSR (Server Side Rendering) technologies such as Angular Universal as @GaurangDhorda said in comments.

Here is a reference to
[Angular Universal Official Page](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

Comment: Wish I could, but I get lots of errors when I run ng add @nguniversal/express-engine

Comment: @ThomasWilliams you need to make sure that the version of `@nguniversal/express-engine` matches the version of `@angular/core`